# My offset seems to be working but pagination is showing the same listings on every page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pagination

I'm making a page that lists items from a SQL database. My pagination uses inView to load the next page when an image is in view. For some reason the first page (Page 1) keeps loading after the initial page (FilterData.php) no matter how much I scroll but the page number is changing.

I'm embarrassed to say I've been trying to debug this for about 3 weeks. Can anyone help me figure out what i'm doing wrong?

**Inventory.php** - Acts as index for this project

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>


    <meta name="Resource-type" content="Document" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />

    <!-- jQuery CDN -->
    <script src="vendors/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery UI JS -->
    <script src="vendors/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- InView JS (jquery.inview.js) -->
    <script src="vendors/js/jquery.inview-master/jquery.inview.js"></script>

    <!-- Infinite scroll -->
    <script src="vendors/js/InfiniteScroll.js"></script>    

    <!-- Search filter -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/js/Filters/Search.js"></script>
    <!-- Filters -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/js/Filters/Filters.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery UI CSS -->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/jquery-ui.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div id="StoneContainer">

            if($query->num_rows > 0){

                //Data goes here
            }

        ?>

    </div>

    <!-- Next page load at NextPage.php -->
    <div class="LoaderContainer">

        <input type="hidden" id="pageno" value="1">
        <img id="Loader" src="../imgs/loader.gif">

    </div>  

    <!-- Filters -->
    <?php include 'vendors/php/Filters/Filters.php'; ?>

</body>

</html>
```

**NextPage.php** - Here is the PHP [pagination] page that the inView AJAX (InfiniteScroll.js) requests

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
        $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
    } else {
        $pageno = $_POST['pageno'];
    }

    $limit = 10;
    $offset = ($pageno>1) * $limit;

    //Include database configuration file
    include('dbConfig.php');

    $SQL = "        
            SELECT
                number,
                image1,
                wt,
                length,
                width,
                CASE
                    WHEN stonetype = 'SA' THEN 'Sapphire'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'RU' THEN 'Ruby'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'TML-P' THEN 'Paraiba'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'EM' THEN 'Emerald'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'TS' THEN 'Tsavorite'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'SI' THEN 'Spinel'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'GT' THEN 'Garnet'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'BER' THEN 'Beryl'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'TML' THEN 'Tourmaline'
                    WHEN stonetype = 'KO' THEN 'Kornerupine'
                    ELSE 'n/a'
                END AS 'stonetype',
                CASE                                    
                    WHEN enhcode = 'H' THEN 'Heated'
                    WHEN enhcode = 'N' THEN 'Unheated'
                    ELSE 'n/a'
                END AS 'enhcode'
            FROM 
                stones
            WHERE 
                wt >= 2.5
    ";

    if(isset($_POST["minimum_wt"], $_POST["maximum_wt"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_wt"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_wt"])) {

        $SQL .= "

            AND wt BETWEEN '".$_POST["minimum_wt"]."' AND '".$_POST["maximum_wt"]."'

        ";
    }

    if(isset($_POST["shape"])) {

        $shape_filter = implode("','", $_POST["shape"]);

        $SQL .= "

            AND stoneshape IN('".$shape_filter."') 

        ";

    }

    if(isset($_POST["color"])) {

        $color_filter = implode("','", $_POST["color"]);

        $SQL .= "

            AND stonecolor IN('".$color_filter."')

        ";

    }

    if(isset($_POST["enhancement"])) {

        $enhancement_filter = implode("','", $_POST["enhancement"]);

        $SQL .= "

            AND enhcode IN('".$enhancement_filter."')

        ";

    }

    if(isset($_POST["matching"])) {

        $matching_filter = implode("','", $_POST["matching"]);

        $SQL .= "

            AND pair IN('".$matching_filter."')

        ";  

    }

    $SQL .= " 

        ORDER BY
            wt ASC
        LIMIT
            " . $offset. ",
            " . $limit. "

    ";

    $res_data = mysqli_query($db, $SQL);

    if(isset($_POST["minimum_wt"], $_POST["maximum_wt"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_wt"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_wt"]) && isset($_POST["shape"]) && isset($_POST["color"]) && isset($_POST["enhancement"]) && isset($_POST["matching"])) {

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)) {

            echo '<div class="Stone">';
                echo'pg. # '; echo $pageno; // temporarily telling me what page the iteration is on

                // landing page
                echo '<a href="Item.php?number='. $row['number'].'">';

                    // image
                    echo '<div class="StoneData StoneIMG"> <img src="../../' . $row['image1']. '"> </div>';

                    // weight 
                    echo '<div class="StoneData">' . $row['wt']. 'Ct</div>';

                    // type
                    echo '<div class="StoneData">' . $row['stonetype']. '</div>';

                    // enhancement
                    echo '<div class="StoneData">' . $row['enhcode']. '</div>';

                    // dimensions
                    echo '<div class="StoneData">' . $row['length']. ' x ' . $row['width']. '</div>';

                    // item number
                    echo '<div class="StoneData"># ' . $row['number']. '</div>';

                echo '</a>';

            echo '</div>'; 

        }

    }

    else {

        echo '';

    }

?>
```

**InfiniteScroll.js** - Here is the AJAX request that loads the NextPage.php when an image is inView

```
//Infinite scroll
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#Loader').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {

        if (isInView) {

            var nextPage = parseInt($('#pageno').val()) + 1;

            //Filters
            var minimum_wt = $('#hidden_minimum_wt').val();
            var maximum_wt = $('#hidden_maximum_wt').val();
            var shape = get_filter('shape');
            var color = get_filter('color');
            var enhancement = get_filter('enhancement');
            var matching = get_filter('matching');

            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: 'vendors/php/NextPage.php',
                data: {
                    pageno: nextPage,
                    minimum_wt: minimum_wt,
                    maximum_wt: maximum_wt,
                    shape: shape,
                    color: color,
                    enhancement: enhancement,
                    matching: matching
                },
                success: function(data){

                    if(data != ''){
                        $('#StoneContainer').append(data);
                        $('#pageno').val(nextPage);
                    } else {
                        $('.LoaderContainer').hide();
                    }

                }

            });

        }

    });

});


//Checking applied filters
function get_filter(class_name) {

    var filter = [];

    $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
        filter.push($(this).val());
    });

    return filter;

}
```

The value of id="pageno" does increase by 1 every time InfiniteScroll.js fires (as expected) but the listings remain the same as page 1

Comment: `$offset = ($pageno>1) * $limit;`  Whatever you're intending that to do, I can pretty much guarantee it isn't what it's actually doing.

Comment: I never said to delete that.  I said that it is most likely not doing what you think it is.  I have no idea what you think it is doing, so I can't say what the correct code would be.  But it's evaluating `($pageno>1)` to `true`, which in math context would be `1`, and then multiplying that `1` by `$limit`.  And you're actually not seeing the first page over and over, you're seeing the second page over and over.  This is due to the fact that you are initializing the `pageno` element to `1`, and then doing `var nextPage = parseInt($('#pageno').val()) + 1;` in your JavaScript.

Comment: This answered my question: it's suppose to be `$offset = ($pageno-1) * $limit;`

Comment: Voting to close as a typo